# Is it possible to filter jsonb arrays with ebean and psql (with query symbol)?

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, ebean

Our DB has several entities with @DbJsonB fields, that holds arrays of strings inside. It could be just great to have ability to execute queries with conditions for jsonb fields, like

```
select * from foo_bars where jsonb_tags ? some_tag;
```

*query symbol means that jsonb_tags array contains some_tag.*
or

```
@ManyToMany
@Where(clause = "roles ? SOME_ROLE")
private List<User> usersWithSomeRole;
```

[psql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

Is it possible to use this syntax with ebean?
For now I have to use plain jdbc connection in some cases with play.db.DB.getConnection(). All my tries with ebean ends with SQLExceptions, with the reason

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for
>   parameter any_number.

May be it's possible to escape query character some way?

Comment: You need to use `??` instead - otherwise the JDBC driver will think the `?` is a parameter.

Comment: You need to include the exact Ebean version and the mapping for DbJsonB. Later Ebean supports mapping "simple types" and falls back to ObjectMapper for other types so you should specify exactly what your mapping is explicitly. It is not clear why you refer to @Where rather than the Ebean JSON expressions like jsonEqualTo() etc.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name working smooth. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed, I had to use double ?? to escape my query.